# How can I say "With the passing of time..."?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, expressions

I am writing a text and I want to say:

> With the passing of time, I have understood what he wanted to say.

I have written:

> 時間がたつにつれて、彼が言いたかったことが分かってきました。

Is my sentence completely wrong?

Comment: I think your sentence is alright.

Answer (score 3):

I think your sentence is great. The only real choice left here is the tone you want to adopt. You chose a polite form of speech with lots of glue words, which conveys a certain signal. In contrast, if you chose a bit more blunt form, it can convey a stronger conviction, with more emphasis on "I".

Also, since your fluency is already pretty high, I shall point out it out, even though it is more of a nit, that three "が" in one sentence feels a little too repetitive. I'd think 彼の言いたかったことが flows a little better.

Finally, a few other variants for your consideration:

- 時が経つにつれ、彼の言わんとした事が分かってきた (more concise, more blunt, and so carries more of your conviction.)
- 今の僕には、あの時の彼の言葉が分かる (contrast now and then, he and I, so it flows more elegantly IMHO.)